# Netbeans cannot find a class file in a jar

Tags: java, netbeans

OK this is driving me crazy, seems so simple and yet it doesn't work. I'm resurrecting a NetBeans project by a former coworker. It depends on some external JARs, in particular JFreeChart. I downloaded new versions of the libraries, and it can find most things, but it cannot seem to search jcommon.

I clearly see the JAR listed under 'Libraries' on the left pane of Netbeans, and I can navigate to exactly where the class file is that Netbeans says it can't find. It's right there! It's also listed under the Libraries tab in the build menu. What's wrong?

[image: Netbeans Screenshot]

Comment: Well it may be case that you have downloaded either newer/older version of jar?

Comment: Yes, it probably is a newer version than what was being used before. But if you look at the error message, netbeans is looking for org.jfree.util.RectangleEdge, and on the left the mouse is pointing at exactly that class...

Comment: It seems issue is with some method call than class (I couldn't exactly see from image posted in question).

Comment: Looks like the library is *there* but it is not part of the class library of your project, thus the IDE can't find the classes when trying to build your project.

Comment: Yes, the error occurs at a call to that class, of course, but the call is fine (according to the docs). Luiggi, what's the difference? I went to Project Properties->Libraries and added the JAR. Is there somewhere else I need to add it additionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well a solution is to nuke the NetBeans projects and make a new project (with the existing source). Then I can add the libraries and everything works fine. Still baffling, but oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Check your import section...if the path to the class in the import is misspelled/outdated it won't be able to find it.

Another possibility - the JFreeChart uses the jcommon jar in it's dependencies, so if these two jars (jfreechart and jcommon) are not in the same folder it may be the cause of your problem.